# Click event not firing when google marker created in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

Folks:

I am trying to activate an infowindow when the marker for USGS Streamflow is clicked using the Google Maps API v3.  The event listener is not firing when the marker is clicked.  The marker layer is created within ajax.  When I hover over the marker, the title shows.

See example map at http://goplay.source3.com.  The javascript is at http://goplay.source3.com/assets/js/outdoor_report.js

I do not see any errors in the console.  The event listener snippet is below; I do not see "ouch" logged in the console.  If I change the listener from streamflowLayer to map an infowindow randomly displays on one of the markers.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(streamflowLayer, 'click', function() {
  console.log('ouch');
  infowindow.open(map,streamflowLayer);
});
```

The function with the ajax call is:

```
function streamflowData(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url : "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&bBox=" + boundsURL + "&parameterCd=00060", 
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(parsed_json) { 
      for (var i = 0; i <= parsed_json.value.timeSeries.length-1; i++) {
        var siteName = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['sourceInfo']['siteName'];
        var siteStreamflow = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['values'][0]['value'][0]['value'];
        var siteLatitude = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['latitude']
        var siteLongitude = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['longitude']
        var siteTime = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['values'][0]['value'][0]['dateTime'];
        var siteLatLong = {lat: siteLatitude, lng: siteLongitude}; 
        streamflowLayer = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLong,
            title: siteName + '\n' + siteStreamflow + ' cfs' + '\n' + 'Date/Time: ' + siteTime,
            icon: streamIcon,
        });
        streamflowMarker.push(streamflowLayer);
        addstreamflowMarker();
      }
    }, // end sucess 
    error: function() {
      // removestreamflowMarker();
      console.log("Zoom in to see streamflows");
    } // end error
  });
}; // end streamflow
```

Please let me know if additional information is needed.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you registering the listener before you add the marker in the map, if so then register the listener after you add the marker in the map.

Comment: Listener is added after adding the marker.

Answer (score 0):

*Listener is added after adding the marker* ...but which marker?

you define/overwrite `streamflowLayer` multiple times:

1. `var streamflowLayer;`
2. `streamflowLayer = new google.maps.Marker();`
3. ```
   streamflowLayer = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: siteLatLong,
             title: siteName + '\n' + siteStreamflow + ' cfs' + '\n' + 'Date/Time: ' + siteTime,
             icon: streamIcon,
         });
   ```

AJAX runs asynchronously, at the moment when you add the listener the response isn't available yet, the listener will be added to the marker created in 2.(what will not have any effect, this marker doesn't have any properties....he is invisible)

The listener will be added to the object that is represented by the variable at the time when you add the listener, when you overwrite this variable later the event will not be inherited by the new object.

You must add separate  listeners to each marker that will be created in the $.ajax-callback.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Now I need to figure out how to retrieve the appropriate marker value.  I am thinking about another ajax call?  Still need to think this through.
 
I commented out 1 and 2 and added "var streamflowLayer..." to 3.  I also moved the click event listener to the streamFlowData() ajax call.  When I place the event listener within the for loop the console logs the last siteName loaded, as expected.

Placing the event listener outside the for loop, and within the success callback, the event listener only works for the latest siteName marker in the for loop.

Comment: I tried to mark your answer as helpful but I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.  Followed Dr. Molle's suggestion and 'Using Closures in Event Listeners' located at  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventClosures

Added the function "attachInfoBox(streamflowLayer, siteName, site_code)" right before the end of the for loop in the ajax call.  attacheInfoBox() has a 'click' even listener that calls infoWindow().  For now, I replaced the infoWindow with a time series graph that loads into a div.  But you can easily enable the infoWindow.  The ajax call looks like:

```
function streamflowData(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url : "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&bBox=" + boundsURL + "&parameterCd=00060", 
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(parsed_json) { 
      for (var i = 0; i <= parsed_json.value.timeSeries.length-1; i++) {
        var siteName = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['sourceInfo']['siteName'];
        var site_code = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['sourceInfo']['siteCode'][0]['value'];
        var siteStreamflow = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['values'][0]['value'][0]['value'];
        var siteLatitude = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['latitude']
        var siteLongitude = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['longitude']
        var siteTime = parsed_json['value']['timeSeries'][i]['values'][0]['value'][0]['dateTime'];
        var siteLatLong = {lat: siteLatitude, lng: siteLongitude}; 
        var streamflowLayer = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLong,
            title: siteName + '\n' + siteStreamflow + ' cfs' + '\n' + 'Date/Time: ' + siteTime,
            icon: streamIcon,
        });
        streamflowMarker.push(streamflowLayer);
        addstreamflowMarker();
        attachInfoBox(streamflowLayer, siteName, site_code);             
      };  // end for
    }, // end sucess 
    error: function() {
      // removestreamflowMarker();
      console.log("Zoom in to see streamflows");
    } // end error
  });
}; // end streamflow
```

The attachInfoBox() function looks like:

```
// attach an infoWindow
function attachInfoBox(marker, siteName, site_code) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
      { content: siteName,
        size: new google.maps.Size(50,50)
      });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // infowindow.open(map,marker);
    getStreamTimeSeries(site_code);      
  });
}
```

getStreamTimeSeries() uses Flot to graph streamflow over time.